# drilldown with 2 uitableviews without fullscreen

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

Is it possible to drilldown `UITableViews` so that the next level is not showing in fullscreen?
I currently have a `UIViewController` with two `UITableViews`. As soon as I click any of the rows in them the next level shows up filling the screen (I'm using `[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES]` for this).
But what I actually want is that if I click on a row in the lower `UITableView` I want the lower `UITableView` to show the next level while the upper one is still showing its content.

Next step would be to use the lower `UITableView` as Filter, so in the next level I can click on some filter options which would then change the upper `UITableView` content (similar to the `SearchBar` where the content changes depending on what you type).

Any ideas how to accomplish the first part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this by adding each `UITableView` inside their own `UIView`. This can then be resized.